# Insert Element between each List element

Tags: java

Is there a better way to insert an Element between each pair of elements into a List in Java than iterating through it

```
List<Integer> exampleInts = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,5,8,13,21)); 

for (int i = 1; i < exampleInts.size(); i++) {
    int delimiter = 0; 
    exampleInts.add(i, delimiter);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Which version of java you are using?

Comment: Here you are not iterating through the elements of the list. You are looping from 1 to exampleInts.size() .... this is not iterating through the list. In addition this code doesn't do what you are asking: it adds delimiter between the first and the second element of your original list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no ready utils for this in standard java libraries.

BTW, your loop is incorrect and will work infinitely until memory end. You should increment `i` variable one more time:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < exampleInts.size(); i++) {
        int delimiter = 0;
        exampleInts.add(i, delimiter);
        i++;
    }
```

or change loop conditions to `for (int i = 1; i < exampleInts.size(); i+=2) {`

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution it is working correctly.

```
List<Integer> exampleInts = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5,
            8, 13, 21));
    int size = (exampleInts.size()-1)*2;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i+=2) {
        int delimiter = 0;
        exampleInts.add(i+1, delimiter);
    }
    System.out.println(exampleInts);
```

Comment: @PKuhn try this solution.

Comment: The result of your program is `[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 8, 0, 13, 0, 21, 0]`, which is not correct, due to the last zero. Btw: I'm not the voter.

Answer (score 0):

In JDK 8+, you can do it this way:

```
private static List<Integer> insert(List<Integer> list, int delimiter) {
    return list.stream().flatMap(i -> Stream.of(i, delimiter)).limit(list.size() * 2 - 1).toList();
}
```

Example use:

```
System.out.println(insert(List.of(1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21), 0).stream().map(String::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
```

The output is:

```
1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 8, 0, 13, 0, 21
```